# Cuando creo objetos iteradamente se eliminan al terminar la iteración?

Tags: python, object, bucles

estoy intentando crear objetos iteradamente para luego tomar sus valores. El problema es que cuando intento traer al objeto fuera de la iteración, este no existe.
Les dejo un ejemplo con el que estuve haciendo pruebas

```
class Custom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prueba = 'prueba'

for x in range(3):
    name = "a" + str(x)
    name = Custom()
    print (name.__dict__)


print (a0.__dict__)
print (a1.__dict__)
print (a3.__dict__)
```

Lo que obtengo es esto:

{'pet': 'dog'}

{'pet': 'dog'}

{'pet': 'dog'}

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gg.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (a0.__dict__)
NameError: name 'a0' is not defined
```

Cómo puedo resolver esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer `name = "a" + str(x)` simplemente estás asignando la cadena `"a0"` a la variable name.

*No estás creando una variable nueva llamada a0.*

A continuación cuando haces `name = Custom()` estás asignando un objeto a la variable `name`, y no a la supuesta variable a0. El anterior valor que tenía `name` (que era `"a0"`), se sustituye por el nuevo valor que es el  objeto creado. Ese objeto lo puedes acceder a través de `name`, pero no de `a0` ya que esta otra variable no existe.

Esto es independiente de que lo hagas dentro de un bucle, aunque naturalmente al iterar vas repitiendo el mismo error n veces.

Creo que lo que buscas se logra haciendo que a sea una lista, y en cada iteración hagas `a.append(Custom())`. Al salir del bucle tendrás tus objetos en `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.

```
class Custom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prueba = 'prueba'

a = []

for x in range(3):
    a.append(Custom())


print (a[0].__dict__)
print (a[1].__dict__)
print (a[2].__dict__)
```

---

```
{'prueba': 'prueba'}
{'prueba': 'prueba'}
{'prueba': 'prueba'}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que comentás! En este caso, los métodos para objetos se siguen utilizando de la misma manera? Es decir, si quiero traer el atributo prueba, puedo hacerlo de esta manera ? getattr(a[0], 'prueba').

Comment: @HernanBernal Sí, o también `a[0].prueba`

Answer (score 1):

primero al hacer esto
name = "a" + str(x)
solo le estas seteando a la variable name un string que seria 'a1', 'a2','a3'... depende de la variable i.
cuando haces esto
name = Custom()
vuelves a setear a la varianle name pero ahora con un objeto el cual es la clase que tienes arriba (Custom)
lo que deberias hacer es crear un array vacio y luego llenarlo con los bjetos que crees en el for , te muestro un ejemplo:

```
def crearListaClases(NumerodeObjetos)
    lista=[]    
    for x in range(NumerodeObjetos):
        name = Custom()
        lista.append(name)
    return lista
```

y la llamas afuera
asi

```
listaClases=crearListaClases(3)  
for clases in listaClases:
    print(clases.__dict__)
```